# Using C# backcolors

Tags: backcolor

In C#, I have a control that wants it's backcolor set by way of an Uint value.
With out running 10's of thousands of permiatations, how do I know what value to use for Light Tan, Dark Green, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's a RGB color Take a hex #RRGGBB and convert to int. So red would be #FF0000, blue is #00FF00, green #0000FF. Just a guess.

So looking at the [Web Color Chart](http://www.brobstsystems.com/colors1.htm), a light tan is #CFC996. Convert that to decimal is 13617558

Good luck